# richfaces file upload is giving error on page : transfer error occured

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2

richfaces file upload is giving error on page : transfer error occured. I am trying to load doc,docx file and i am getting error mentioned above. I am following 
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf?c=fileUpload. Please give relevant solution or some other option for file upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved it was due to value of attribute (allowFlash) whose value must be false otherwise transfer error occured message appears...